# I want to run multiple [Test Method] in my program. And want to close the browser session after every [Test Method]

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mstest

Remember: I don't see any issue when my test pass. I see the issue when the test fails.

Issue: I am running `[Test Method] -1`  and giving the wrong Xpath for `Test-1` to handle fail scenario.

My driver keeps waiting on browser since XPath is wrong, but at the end, it's not closing the browser session. The driver is throwing a fail status on test explorer.

I want the driver to close the session whether test fails for any reason.

## TestClass.cs

I am running lots of `[Test Method]`

```
[Test Method]
public void Test1()
{
    try{
        Assert.IsTrue(ProgramPage.checkTest1());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw ; 
    }
}


[Test Method]
public void Test2()
{
    try{
        Assert.IsTrue(ProgramPage.checkTest2());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw ; 
    }
}
```

## ProgramPage.cs

I define page logic and Page objects

```
// can we put try and catch block on Assert ?? 
// it's simple display check example
public static class {

    public static IWebElement webElement = null ; 

    public static void checkTest1()
    {
        try {
            webElement = driver.FindElement(xpath--1);

            if(webElement.Displayed)
            {
                Console.Write("element is visible ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("element is not visible");
            }
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw ;
        }
    }

    public static void checkTest2()
    {
        try {
            webElement = driver.FindElement(xpath--2);
            // SAY THIS XPATH is Wrong 

        if(webElement.Displayed)
        {
            Console.Write("element is visible ");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("element is not visible");
        }
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw ;
    }
}

// when test fail on wrong Xpath , driver does not close the Browser session
```

## Driver.cs

I initialize driver and close from here.

```
public static class{

    // I am not having private driver for each class , is that an issue ?
    [Test Initialize]
    public void  Init()
    {
        //initialize the driver 
        //launch and login the browser
    }


    [Test Cleanup]
    public void Close()
    {
        Driver.Close(); //  IT has to be executed no matter
        // what the test result is 
    }

}
```

Comment: I removed the old question and added all comments in one single question. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why are you running them as test methods and not just tests?

Comment: Because I am using MSTest not NUnit, It's a requirement. Run [Test] or [TestMethod] will not make much difference. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I don't know... sounds wonky to me. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that you are catching exceptions? If test2's XPath is incorrect, it will throw an exception which you are catching. Do you have an `Assert.Fail()` in the `catch` to fail the test? Maybe it never finishes?

Comment: I tried even not to throw exception rather return "true/false" , but it never worked  for me. It's keep failing on Wrong Xpath line and not able to move on to next line even you throw exception or not. I have Assert only in [Test Method] , I not putting Assert in other Page classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the class non static and write TestInitialize and TestCleanup without spaces.

Example:

```
public class BasicTestClass
{
    private IWebDriver driver;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void  Init()
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.nl");
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Close()
    {
        Driver.Close();
    }

    // TestMethods go here
}
```

Also, it seems strange to put a test class into a file named Driver.cs

Comment: I am sorry. I wrote something on Notepad because I do not want to mistakely put something company specific. You are correct my Base codes are in BaseClass. I am sorry again to put static , in my real code it's not Static at all. And TestInitialize and TestCleanup are off course without space. I wrote in a way to give us readability here.